# CSS overrriding for line height

Tags: css

I use Boostrap with SPRFLAT. Boostrap.css file can be overridden from custom.css file.

I wanted to override the line height for table > tbody > tr > td element.

The only way was override all the following element.

```
.table > thead > tr > th,
.table > tbody > tr > th,
.table > tfoot > tr > th,
.table > thead > tr > td,
.table > tbody > tr > td,
.table > tfoot > tr > td {

  line-height: 1.428571429;

}
```

I tried the following code.

```
.table > tbody > tr > td,
{

  line-height: 1.428571429;

}
```

**and**

```
#ticketstable .table > tbody > tr > td, 
{

    line-height: 25px !important;
}
```

This doesn't work. Can anybody help me to find the issue?

Comment: Look at the cascade for this item in devtools style inspector to see where the styles are coming from, your own CSS or (most likely) somewhere else. Do you know how to do that? If so, you'll have a very hard time debugging this or any other CSS problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your rule (`.table > tbody > tr > td`) has equal specificity to the Bootstrap CSS rule, so it will not necessarily override. The more specific rule will apply, so in this case you can fix it by making your rule more specific:

```
table.table > tbody > tr > td
```

Or if you have a surrounding CSS class you would like to use:

```
.myclass .table > tbody > tr > td
```